# R pagedown/shinyapps error - Google Chrome cannot be found

Tags: r, shiny-server, shinyapps, pagedown

I've been trying to use the `pagedown` package to create a pdf from a html which is better formatted and more presentable from a shinyapp.  It tested fine locally on my machine.  After deployment, the document failed to download with the following error from the logs:

```
Warning: Error in find_chrome: Cannot find Chromium or Google Chrome
[No stack trace available]
```

I am using Google Chrome to view the app but I am guessing there's more to it than this?

The code for the download is as follows:

```
output$downloadDrug <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {("drug-instructions.pdf)},

    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report_drugHTML.Rmd')
      src2 <- normalizePath("printout.css")
      label <- normalizePath("pxLabel.png")
      logo <-normalizePath("logo.png")
      fasting <- normalizePath("fasting.png")

      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report_drugHTML.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
      file.copy(src2, "printout.css", overwrite = TRUE)
      file.copy(label, "pxLabel.png", overwrite = TRUE)
      file.copy(logo, "logo.png", overwrite = TRUE)
      file.copy(fasting, "fasting.png", overwrite = TRUE)

      library(rmarkdown)
      out <- render('report_drugHTML.Rmd', 
                    params = list(name = input$px_name, dob = input$dob),
                    'html_document')
      library(pagedown)
      out <- pagedown::chrome_print(out, "drug-instructions.pdf")
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I am still a novice so please feel free to point out the obvious.

Comment: A complete, minimal example that reproduces the error would go a long way to get people's help.

Comment: I am not sure how to produce this as it will need code on my app, my R markdown and data. The problem seems to also happen when it is deployed, as it works fine on my machine

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the page is "printed" on the server side. So I guess Chrome is not available on the machine where your app is deployed.